# Mandrill API - download email content

Tags: mandrill

We are currently using Mandrill to send emails. We use mandrill quite a few different systems to send emails.

Is there any API way to get the content of a sent email? I Know mandrill stores a copy for up to 30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, there's not an API for the email contents. If you're using templates, you can use the [templates/render](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/templates.JSON.html#method=render) API call to get the rendered HTML of a template with merge tags and the like, but it isn't the actual content of a sent email.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`messages.content`](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=content) method, you just need the API key and the message ID (which is returned in the [send](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=send-template) call).

Bear in mind that Mandrill only saves the content for 24h by default, and it can be extended up to 30 days by paying. So make sure you make the `messages.content` call within that time frame.

Also, other people have had trouble when calling `messages.content` too soon, as it appears that the content takes a bit to be indexed (see answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000046/no-message-exists-with-the-id-id))