# Mandrill - How do I retrieve the message content html that was just sent?

Tags: php, mandrill

I'm using the Mandrill API with PHP.

I am sending a mail message:

```
$result = $mandrill->messages->sendTemplate($template_name, $template_content, $message);
$mandrill_return_data = current($result);
```

Since the message content is only saved for 24 hours, I would like to retrieve the html that was just sent and save it into my DB.

```
$message_content = $mandrill->messages->content($mandrill_return_data['_id'])['html'];
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and returns the following error:

> A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill_Unknown_Message - No message
>   exists with the id '446740d7b61e4403b11379db4e1d45b0'

I did some googling and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000046/no-message-exists-with-the-id-id) and it explains that it takes a few minutes to index the message in their system and I noticed this to be the case. Now I am trying to figure out a solution on how to retrieve the message content html and save it into my DB.

I suppose I could use a cron job to run every few hours or after it sends the message, or I could run an AJAX command to retrieve the message content html after a specified timeout, but both of those solutions seem hacky. I'm hoping for a more elegant solution that doesn't require a whole lot of additional code. Any ideas?